# How do you view the name of a PostScript Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, postscript

How do I find the NAMES of PostScript dictionaries?

Viewing a PostScript dictionary simply puts a -dict- on the stack.
Yes, the contents are easily viewed with {== ==} forall.
Yes, a sample content name can be found with {== exit} forall
Yes, the count of the stored items can easily be found.

And, yes, the total content of all dictionaries can be found
with something similar to 
https://www.tinaja.com/psutils/snoop2a.psl  WHEN and IF you know their names ahead of time.

But how can I DIRECTLY find the name of the current dictionary?

Expected: A name object like /userdict

Comment: I have some old code which can do this, iff the the dict is defined somewhere on the dictstack. http://web.archive.org/web/20160404161545/https://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=ds.ps&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the name of a PostScript dictionary, because PostScript dictionaries don't have names.

When you associate a dictionary object with a name what you are doing is creating a key/value pair in another dictionary. The key is the name and the value is the dictionary. If you don't specify another dictionary to create the pair in, then they will be created in the current dictionary. If you haven't called 'begin' then userdict is usually the current dictionary.

So if you do something like:

```
/MyDict 10 dict def
```

What you are doing is creating a dictionary object and associating it with the name /MyDict in the current dictionary. When you later do `MyDict` The interpreter searches the current dictionary and then all other dictionaries on the dictionary stack looking for a key which is the name /MyDict. When it finds that key it pulls the associated dictionary and pushes it on the operand (or dictionary) stack.

The name is **never** associated with the dictionary other than as a key/value pair in another dictionary.

Consider this:

```
/MyDict1 /MyDict2 10 dict dup def def
```

That creates two key/value pairs in the current dictionary, one has the key /MyDict1 the other has the key /MyDict2, but **both** of those keys are associated with the same dictionary. So what would the name of the dictionary be ?

Notice that composite objects like dictionaries and arrays are treated lilke pointers in PostScript. When you do `dup` on a composite object it doesn't create a new array or dictionary and copy all the contents of the original (plus all the contents of any composite objects in the original), it just pushes another pointer to the same already allocated object.

If you want to have your dictionaries contina a name, then you need to store a key/value pair **inside** the dictionary. Eg:

```
<<
  /Name /MyDict1
>>
```

or something similar.

There are special dictionaries which are always on the dictionary stack and cannot be removed; systemdict, globaldict and userdict (some implementations may have more).

[Later thinks]
You could, of course, write a PostScript program which, given a dictionary, checks all the dictionaries in userdict, systemdict and globaldict against the current dictionary to see if the are `eq` by using forall and checking the type of the value for 'dict'. That way you would have the associated name as the other parameter.

Obviously, by making the checking routine recursive (ie if this is not the dictionary we want, check all the dictionaries in this dictionary), you would then be able to check the entire currnetly available tree of dictionaries to see if they are the dictionary for which you want the associated name.

You could either exit the loop and recursion as soon as a match is found, or continue checking every available dictionary to see if the dictionary is referenced elsewhere.

Comment: Say deep in a PS program I define a dictionary with /woof. Inside this dictionary is another dictionary defined as /bark. /woof is clearly the name associated with the higher dictionary and /bark is the name associated with the more inside dictionary.

Comment: A program puts the bark dictionary on top of the stack. == reports this as --dict--. How to I get from --dict-- to the name /woof? One sometimes route would be to create a master list of all known dictionary lengths. Check the length for a possible hit. I need something more "official" and more elegant.

Comment: Yes, a slow and complex /findnameofhostdictionary routine could be written, creating an entire current "dictionary tree map" . I guess what I am really asking for is if I missed some simple and obvious misuse of   faster and shorter and cleaner code.

Comment: No, there's no way to find the key associated with an object in any current dictionary without traversing the dictionary stack and examining each object to see if its the one you want. Sorry but that's the way it is. You might also want to bear in mind that the key in a key/value pair doesn't need to be a name. Ghostscript has some nefarious code in which the key of a key/value dictionary pair is **itself** a dictionary.

Comment: I have a function [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404161545/https://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=ds.ps&can=2&q=) called `wherevalue` which searches dictionaries with `forall` just like you describe.